# Unable to configure Apache to serve static content for CherryPy app. What I am doing wrong?

Tags: apache, static, cherrypy, mod-proxy, mod-ssl

I have Apache 2.2.15 configured with Mod_Proxy and Mod_SSL and serving CherryPy web application on RHEL 6.3.  The only thing I'm struggling with is getting Apache to serve the website's static content (*.js, *.css, *.jpg).  Here is my VirtualHost entry...

```
<VirtualHost mydomain.com:443>
ServerAdmin support@mydomain.com
ServerName mydomain.com
ProxyPreserveHost On
SSLProxyEngine On
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/myserver.key
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/mydomain_com.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/mydomain_com.ca-bundle

# this prevents the follow URL path from being proxied
ProxyPass static/ !

# setup the proxy
<Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / http://www.mydomain.com:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.mydomain.com:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

For instance the path to my css file is the following...

```
/var/www/html/mydomain/static/style.css
```

Since I'm forcing the entire site to be in https when I navigate to

```
https://www.mydomain.com/static/style.css
```

or

```
http://www.mydomain.com/static/style.css
```

My browser tells me the page is not found (404).  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
it appears that Apache is still proxying /static... I found this redirect when accessing the /static/style.css in my Apache access log...

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [17/Sep/2012:08:46:06 -0400] "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 301 337 "https://www.mydmain.com/Home/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0.7) Gecko/20120826 Firefox/10.0.7"
```

anyone know why that is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Andrew

Comment: Have you tried `ProxyPass /static/ !`?

Comment: Yes - with same result.  I ended up using nginx.  Got nginx configured pretty quickly... about 1 hr for ssl support and serving static content.  However, still working to pass a nessus scan in order to be PCI compliant.  Have a few errors remaining.

Comment: @AndrewKloos Are you able to figure out the issue? If yes, can you please post the answer.

Comment: @Abdul Azeez No I could not get apache to serve the static content.  I ended up using nginx web server for my setup.  If that interests you I could setup a tutorial for how I configured nginx with cherrypy.

Comment: @AndrewKloos Thanks for the reply. I added Alias for the static location before proxypass and it worked fine. Alias /portal/images/ /var/www/portal/images/

Comment: @Abdul Azeez That's awesome!  Unfortunately I don't have the setup to test your answer but if you give it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding an alias for your static folder before ProxyPass. It worked like champ for me,

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/html/mydomain/static/
```

Comment: After adding Alias to my static folder, Apache started serving static files through http2 protocol. Before that only dynamic pages was served in http2

Answer (score 1):

If the static files are under the "main" source folder, I'd suggest telling CherryPy to serve the specific folder(s) for stylesheets, images, js etc

Personally I generate the config and then use that config when mounting the application like:

```
app = cherrypy.tree.mount(Root(), script_name="", config=somefile.get_config())
```

An example of static file serving with CherryPy.

- The `/css` is the path that you use from within your templates or
  HTML.
- The `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)` generates a path pointing to your index file (or some other script if your not starting quickstart() from within the index)
- The above path is then followed by the relative path to your static content folder

File:

```
##somefile
def get_config():
    return {
        '/':
        {
            'tools.encode.on': True,
            'tools.encode.encoding': 'UTF-8'
        },
        '/css':
        {
            'tools.staticdir.on': True,
            'tools.staticdir.dir': os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'relative/path/to/your/css/folder'))
        },
        '/js':
        {
            'tools.staticdir.on': True,
            'tools.staticdir.dir': os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'relative/path/to/your/js/folder'))
        }
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer but this doesn't answer my question.  I'm trying to figure out why apache won't serve static content.